# SN74AHCT595 Unused Pin

Tags: 74hc595

I use SN74AHCT595 for i2s IC

can I connecting unused pin to GND like below Picture ?

[image]

Answer (score 7):

No, that will short the outputs and cause excessive heating in the chip if they attempt to drive high.

The rule for CMOS chips such as 74AHCTxxx is to tie unused *inputs* to a valid logic level, directly or through a resistor (the latter gives you some flexibility if you later decide to use them it's easier to add a bodge wire), and leave unused *outputs* **open**.

If the inputs have an internal pull-up or pull-down then you can leave them open but that's not the case here (nor is it true for most CMOS logic chips in the 4000 or 74xx series).

Comment: Okay, I will follow your instruction and let the unused Pin Open.

Comment: Unused *outputs* just to be clear. QA, QG, QH, QH' are outputs. The others are power pins or inputs.

Comment: okay .......

Answer (score 2):

All unused **inputs** must be tied either to Vcc or to GND to ensure proper device operation p.4 SN74AHCT595 datasheet (Recommended Operating Conditions)
[image: recommended operating condition note]

however outputs should never be pulled above Vcc

Comment: I decided to let the unused output pin open.